# How to search for a string within an array substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array like this.If atleast one of the substrings within the array have the value i'm searching for it should pass.

```js
Value1 = [
  "Grape | 100 |Food Catering Service",
  "Apple | 100,000m |Food Catering Service",
  "Water Melon | 100,000m |Catering Service Outside",
  "100,000m |Food Catering Service Outside
]
```

Using typescript i'm trying to make sure that atleast if a substring in the array there is the value Food.
Even though the third substring within this arrat has no food it should still pass.

Code i've tried so far but does not do the job. It just returns the array

```
export function arraySubstring (expected:string, ignoreCase?: boolean): Expectation<string[], string> {
 return Expectation.that("test", expected, 
    async(actor: Actor, actual: string[]): Promise<boolean> ==> {

  try {
   for (const value of actual) {
     if(ignoreCase) {
       if (!value.toLowerCase().includes(expected.toLowerCase())) return 
         false;
     } else {
         if (!value.includes(expected)) return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
})
}

const value2= await webActor.attemptsTo(Ensure.that("my expectation", 
value1, arraySubstring ("Food")))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output you need. Your written spec is not quite clear.

Comment: @O.Jones is that more explanatory. So if i declare that const value2. if it compares the array value1 and Food. My assertion should be true

Comment: Also please remember to properly indent your code, because you _want_ people to be able to easily read your code.

Comment: Why should the third that does not have the keyword pass ?

Comment: @charlietfl if atleast one of the substrings within the array have the value i'm searching for it should pass. Since atleast 3 have it then it should pass.

Comment: So if it exists anywhere in the array the whole array should be included? Confusing and unusual. Please [edit] question to make the conditions unambiguous and clear

Comment: @charlietfl that is kind of what i'm trying to achieve. The condition is pretty clear.  The array can contain a bunch of information. As far as the string"Food" exists within any of the array substrings, my assertion should pass.

Putting it this way aswell if one or more strings within the array substring contain "Food"

Comment: You can  use `Array.some()` which returns a boolean if condition is met for any element in the array

Comment: Or `stringArray.join('').includes(expected)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code relies on it's order. If the first element that gets looped contains no "food", it will return false. Return statements always exit the function.

I'd suggest to create a single string and check the index of the first occurance with `indexOf("food")`, something like that.

```js
const array = [
  "Grape | 100 |Food Catering Service",
  "Apple | 100,000m |Food Catering Service",
  "Water Melon | 100,000m |Catering Service Outside",
  "100,000m |Food Catering Service Outside",
];

const found = array
  .reduce((obj, entry) => obj.concat(entry))
  .toLocaleLowerCase()
  .indexOf("food");
if (found >= 0) {
  console.log("Array contains food");
} else {
  console.log("Array does not contain food");
}
```

If you want to iterate you need to return on the true case, this will remove the importance of order from your code.

```js
const array = [
  "Grape | 100 |Food Catering Service",
  "Apple | 100,000m |Food Catering Service",
  "Water Melon | 100,000m |Catering Service Outside",
  "100,000m |Food Catering Service Outside",
];

const ignoreCase = true;
const expected = "Food";

const containsExptected = (_array) => {
  for (const value of _array) {
    if (ignoreCase) {
      if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) >= 0) return true
    } else {
      if (value.indexOf(expected) >= 0) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

const found = containsExptected(array);
if (found) {
  console.log("Array contains food");
} else {
  console.log("Array does not contain food");
}
```

Comment: Isn't it  `>=0` instead of `>0`?

Comment: Thanks@Deepak i fixed that in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner to check for a match of substring in an array of strings:

```js
const value = ["Grape | 100 |Food Catering Service", "Apple | 100,000m |Food Catering Service", "Water Melon | 100,000m |Catering Service Outside", "100,000m |Food Catering Service Outside"]

const expected = "Food"
const ignoreCase = true
console.log(value.some(val => (ignoreCase ? val.toLowerCase().includes(expected.toLowerCase()) : val.includes(expected))))
```